# Android - detect Button touch (not OnTouchListener)

Tags: android

I'm facing a problem. I want to do some actions when user is touching a button. I have a buttom with this background:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="false">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="@color/md_light_blue_A400" />
            <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="20dp" android:bottomRightRadius="1dp" android:topLeftRadius="1dp" android:topRightRadius="1dp"  />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_pressed="true" >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="@color/md_blue_900" />
            <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="20dp" android:bottomRightRadius="1dp" android:topLeftRadius="1dp" android:topRightRadius="1dp"  />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

it's changing color on button click

But when I implement `OnTouchListener` for this button color is no more changing.

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
     @Override
     public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
         if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
             //do something when touching button
             return true;
         } else if (event.equals(MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)) {
             //do something when not touching button
             return true;
         }
         else {
             return false;
         }

      }
});
```

The problem is the background of the button is not changing when implementing `OnTouchListener`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you are consuming the event and doing it on touch does not let the system invoke its functionality.

The onTouchDocumentation says

> Called when a touch event is dispatched to a view. This allows
>   listeners to get a chance to respond before the target view.
>
> Parameters v  The view the touch event has been dispatched to.
>   event The MotionEvent object containing full information about the
>   event. Returns True if the listener has consumed the event, false
>   otherwise.

If you really want to override on touch, you should return false to get the behaviour you are  expecting.

Comment: perfect, returning false did the think

Answer (score 0):

You can call the button click method from within onTouch:

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
 @Override
 public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
     if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
         //do something when touching button
         button.performClick();
         return true;
     } else if (event.equals(MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)) {
         //do something when not touching button

         return true;
     }
     else {
         return false;
     }

  }
});
```

If you don't have an onClickListener, this should trip the selector to change color.